# AngularJS routing prevent default and continue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

When user tries to leave a page without saving I have this:

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    if ($rootScope.madeChange) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $rootScope.ConfirmationModal.leavePage(); // ask if the user is 
      // sure about leaving the page. 
      // if he says yes, I need to continue the page changed.
    }
  });
```

However I don't find a way to continue after stopped the default.

I have tried: `$location.path("/some-page");`

but this didn't work.

Also tried `return true;`

Also tried use the `next` param by `next();`.

Comment: Use UI-router it's better

Comment: Saying "didn't work" is not helpful. The general practice is to have the modal return a promise. What router are you using? For `ui-router`, use the `$stateChangeStart` event; for `ng-route` use the `$routeChangeStart` event. Use the `$locationChangeStart` event only if you are creating your own routing.